# RailsのActiveRecordでcreated_atを検索したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

RailsのActiveRecordで2015年7月に作成されたデータを検索したい場合にはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

また、さらに詳しく2015年7月20日に作成された日、などの検索の仕方を教えていただけるとたすかります。

Comment: snxpwfさんにお願いがあります。snxpwfさんの質問一覧を確認したところ、「解決済み」になっている質問が一つもないようでした。この質問に限らず、解決に役立った回答があれば回答に「解決済み」フラグ（緑のチェックマーク）を立ててください。解決済みにすると以下のようなメリットがあります。 「1. フラグを立てることでsnxpwfさんの信用度（システム上のポイント）が上がります。 2. 同じような問題で困っている人がアクセスしてきたときに「この回答が役に立ったんだな」とわかります。 3. 回答者が「自分の回答が役に立った！」と嬉しい気持ちになります。」もし解決していなければコメント等で解決しなかった理由を書いてもらえれば、回答者はさらに回答を追記してくれるかもしれません。質問者と回答者が協力して、お互いに良い関係を作り出していきましょう！

Answer (score 2, accepted):

僕ならこんな感じでやりますね。

```
User.where(created_at: "2015-07-01".in_time_zone.all_month)
# SQL => SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-07-01 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-07-31 23:59:59.999999')

User.where(created_at: "2015-07-20".in_time_zone.all_day)
# SQL => SELECT "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE ("users"."created_at" BETWEEN '2015-07-20 00:00:00.000000' AND '2015-07-20 23:59:59.999999')
```

ちなみにデータの件数が何万件もあるような場合だと検索に時間がかかるので created_at にインデックスを貼っておくのが良いと思います。